# JSON.parse throws errors while eval doesn't on the same strings. Why?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

suppose I have something like

```
var a = '["\t"]'
```

If I do

```
eval('var result = ' + a)
```

Everything works fine. But if I do

```
var result = JSON.parse(a)
```

It throws error: Unexpected token.

Same happens with \b, \f: works with eval, while fails with JSON.parse. Why? Shouldn't the parser behave in the same way when encounters "\t"?

On the other hand, both eval and JSON.parse fail with a \n (as expected), but they also both fail with a \r. Why is this?

I'm a little bit confused with all this so could anybody explain what is going on? If possible with details: how is the parser behaving in the two cases?

Comment: `var a = '["\\t"]'`.  You need to escape the backslash.

Comment: You can't have literal tab character inside a JSON string literal. The tab has to be encoded as `\t`. `'["\t"]'` produces the string `[" "]` which is invalid JSON.

Comment: Your string isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Guys I understanf this. I am asking WHY?

Comment: Because that's how JSON is defined. See the "string" production rule in  http://json.org/ (a tab is a control character). It's the same rule that disallows line breaks in JSON strings. If you are asking why it is defined like that, ask Crockford, he invented it.

Comment: @Core_dumped: Try `alert('["\t"]')` to see what your string actually is.

Comment: Why does \r fail with eval then?

Comment: @Core_dumped: because it is the same as a line break and JS sting literals cannot span multiple lines (without escaping the line break).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, was wondering cause when I write it in a string I get "" and not ""(the second " on the next line, like with \n)

Comment: You have to distinguish between the content of a string and source text. Since you are `eval`ing the contents of the string, it is evaluated as source text, and the control character represented by `\r` is treated according to these rules: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape `\` in the JavaScript string, so you'd end up with

```
var a = '["\\t"]'
```

For details, please refer to "http://json.org/"

Comment: Can you explain why is this happening. I

Comment: Where do you see `\-`?

Answer (score 2):

Well that's because it's not valid JSON.

Don't try to write JSON yourself. Instead, use `JSON.stringify` to properly encode your data.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(["\t"]);
JSON.parse(json);
//=> ["\t"]
```